# Continuity vs Chronology

Tags: discussion, tags

So I'd like to discuss these two tags:

[continuity](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuity) : Question regarding the continuity of events in a film or TV series.

[chronology](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronology) : Question regarding order of occurrence in a film or TV series.

First off, defining continuity with *continuity* is [**brilliant**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_definition).

Secondly, as currently used in many cases, these should be synonyms...

**BUT**

In film making, there is an actual thing called [*continuity*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_editing#Continuity) and I think **that** is what this tag is **supposed** to be for.

> Continuity is a film term that suggests that a series of shots should be physically continuous, as if the camera simply changed angles in the course of a single event. For instance, if in one shot a beer glass is empty, it should not be full in the next shot. Live coverage of a sporting event would be an example of footage that is very continuous. Since the live operators are cutting from one live feed to another, the physical action of the shots matches very closely. Many people regard inconsistencies in continuity as mistakes, and often the editor is blamed. In film, however, continuity is very nearly last on a film editor's list of important things to maintain.

Granted, a lot of what would likely be discussed in this definition might fall under the canopy of **trivia**... which we don't want... it is the correct use of the term in our film-centric world.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  Are you saying chronology is redundant - because I would disagree, for example movies can have non-linear storylines (e.g. mnemento) which has nothing specifically to do with the craft of continuity - which is avoiding inconsistencies between shots.

Comment: I'm saying that, in common use, they're being utilized interchangeably (and sometimes people are using both tags)... and usually, continuity is being used incorrectly.  I guess I'm mostly just recommending an updated definition and removing it from questions that are really talking about chronology.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **I don't think they are to be synonyms**, since they are about different topics. It is true that those topics can sometimes overlap a bit, but at the end of the day they're different topics with vastly different questions. But I agree that at least the [continuity](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuity) tag is used a bit inconsistently for things where the [chronology](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronology) tag might also apply. This might be grounded in the less than clear and unconfusing definition of that tag.

But let's first look at the easier [chronology](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronology). This seems to apply to the **chronology of events in a movie/TV-show's story** (to which *continuity* can sometimes be a key/contradiction/...). And as of now the questions with this tag seem to give a good and fitting overview of the kinds questions that this applies to.

You already give a movie-related definition of *continuity*, but this seems too narrow to me. I would not consider *continuity* only as shot-to-shot continuity in the sense of "movie-mistakes" as given by that quote of yours. In this case it would hardly apply to many questions, which would either be off-topic *"hey look at that stupid error"* stuff or valid questions already tagged with [production-mistakes](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/production-mistakes) (which ought to be used only when it's clear that it's a mistake, though). I would rather see it in a broader sense of any kind of **cross-scene, cross-movie or cross-episode continuity, not only in a visual sense but also story-wise**, to use a variation of your own words:

> discussions regarding any kind of consistency between shots, scenes, or releases (i.e. movies/episodes/seasons).

We'd still have to be careful, though, that it doesn't become an easy-out compensation for the lack of the <s>good</s> old [plot-inconsistency](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-inconsistency) tag.

Now when looking at story-wise continuity it might be easy to confuse *chronology* and *continuity* but noone said there can't be a bit of overlap. I for myself would say that [chronology](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronology) is strictly about the temporal (well yeah, who guessed it) oder of events and asking what this order is or if there is one to be expected. [continuity](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuity) on the other hand seems to apply when there already is to be expected some kind of chronological (or otherwise) continuity in the first place. Afterall, **those tags seem to be quite orthogonal and when its about temporal continuity, nobody prohibits the use of both tags**.

---

Now let's look at the questions tagged that way. There are some where I think this definition applies well and they deserve the [continuity](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuity) tag. But I agree that some of them might even deserve [chronology](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronology) in addition to that, when they're more about the broader timeline of the events and the question *if* there is a continuity to be upheld in the first place:

- [How does so much time pass between Prison Break seasons 1 and 2?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/23394/49)
- [Why isn't James Bond a code name?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/21826/49)
- [Is Broccoli Rob dead?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/21533/49)
- https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/16711/49
- [How is the Tesseract still in Odin's trophy room during Thor?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/12567/49)
- [Has the continuity timeline been established for the new X-men movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/8839/49)
- [How the new Omnitrix watch connected to the old Ultimatrix plot?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/8412/49)
- [Is there any continuity between James Bond movies that have different actors portraying the title character?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/8278/49)
- [When/Why did American television change from primarily episodic to primarily serialized?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/3147/49)
- [How to explain the discrepancies between the end of Prometheus and the beginning of Alien?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/2631/49)
- [Gun Scene in Goldeneye](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/2160/49)
- [Linking between Season 1 and Season 2 of Black Adder?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/9184/49)
- [Boston Public episode order. Was Chapter 34 aired out of order in the original run? Why?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/29976/49)

Other questions don't have anything to do with continuity specifically and might deserve other tags:

- [How did they get back in “City on the Edge of Forever”?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/15477/49)
- [Why did Spock not know about Romulans in “Balance of Terror”?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/14574/49)
- [How does Gibbs get his boats out of his basement?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/8969/49)

And others seem to apply only for the [chronology](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronology) tag but not so much for [continuity](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuity):

- [How do the events in The Day of the Doctor relate to those in The End of Time?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/15427/49)
- [How much time has passed between Series 1 and 2 of Game of Thrones?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/12689/49)
- [How do the Dallas movies fit between the old and new shows?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/9218/49)

---

So all in all I don't see many problems with the current use of [chronology](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronology) and [continuity](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuity), even if the latter might sometimes be a little misused or sometimes just both apply. But all in all, if there are situations where it isn't entirely clear, there might as well be both tags appropriate or it depends more on the way the question is asked. Not a definite answer, I agree, but it largely works currently, I think. And **improving the tag wiki might not hurt**.